# Pandas: Inputing another row into dataframe based on date

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
date    people  flight
0   04/12/61    1   Vostok 1
1   04/15/61    0   Vostok 2
2   05/04/61    0   none
3   05/05/61    1   Freedom 7
4   05/09/61    0   none
5   07/20/61    0   none
```

I want to input another row between values where a flight ends and turns to a different flight/or none. The row should have the date that is one day before the changed value (and **keep** the ***name of the flight*** and ***number of people*** beforehand too. So the final date would look like this:

```
0   04/12/61    1   Vostok 1
1   04/14/61    1   Vostok 1
2   04/15/61    0   Vostok 2
3   05/04/61    0   none
4   05/05/61    1   Freedom 7
5   05/08/61    1   Freedom 7
6   05/09/61    0   none
7   07/20/61    0   none
```

Sorry for the very specific question- but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What about the none after `Vostok 1`?

Comment: @RafaelC I just added that part- thanks!

Comment: @RafaelC oh wait; the none after vostok1 is already 4/12/61 the day right before that

Comment: @jezrael  
Do you have a method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.replace({0:np.nan,'none':np.nan}).bfill(limit=1).fillna({'people':0,'flight':'none'})
Out[19]: 
       date  people    flight
0  04/12/61     1.0   Vostok1
1  04/13/61     0.0      none
2  05/04/61     1.0  Freedom7
3  05/05/61     1.0  Freedom7
4  05/09/61     0.0      none
5  07/20/61     0.0      none
```

Update

```
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)

sdx=df.index[df.people.eq(1)]


tempdf=pd.DataFrame({'date':(df.loc[sdx,'date']-pd.to_timedelta('1 days')).values,'people':df.loc[sdx,'people'].values,'flight':df.loc[sdx,'flight'].values
              },index=sdx+1)


pd.concat([df,tempdf]).sort_values('date').sort_index()

        date    flight  people
0 2061-04-12   Vostok1       1
1 2061-04-11   Vostok1       1
1 2061-04-15   Vostok2       0
2 2061-05-04      none       0
3 2061-05-05  Freedom7       1
4 2061-05-04  Freedom7       1
4 2061-05-09      none       0
5 2061-07-20      none       0
```

Comment: When I try to run 
`final.replace({0:np.nan,'none':np.nan}).bfill(limit=1).fillna({'people':0,'flight':'none'})`

it says `NameError: name 'np' is not defined`

Comment: @boboT import numpy as np

Comment: Good solution !

Comment: This is the last question- I promise. What should I write if instead of inputing it before every none, I input it everytime the values change. So a Freedom 7 to a Freedom 9 would have the same effect as a Freedom 7 to none

Comment: @boboT sorry I can not get it , would you like show your expected output to me ?

Comment: @Wen I edited the original question's example so its easier to read/understand

Comment: @Wen it looks like the year now starts with 20? (2061)

Comment: @boboT you can do `df.date=df.date.apply(lambda x : x.replace(year=1961))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174826/discussion-between-bobo-t-and-wen).

Comment: @boboT`df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date.dt.year.sub(100).astype(str)+'-'+df.date.dt.strftime('%m-%d'))
`

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you have also an integer index. make it a column (added_column). Then create another dataframe identical to the original one.

```
df_copy = df.copy()
```

in df_copy increase the index by 1

```
df_copy["added_column"] += 1
```

join df and df_copy using added_column, use suffixes (_original and _copy) to differentiate columns from the original dataframe and copied ones. let's call the result df_merged.

If my understanding is correct, the records you want to include in your dataframe are the following (you have also to reduce date_copy by one day):

df_merged[df_merged.flight.notnull()][[date_copy, people_original, flight_original]]